# SUM of column conditional to many values of another column

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to accomplish something, but don't know how to do it.

I have a Dimension (Table called TEntry) that represents time entries for employees like so :

```
    Id | EmployeeId | EntryDT    | TimeInMinutes | PriceAgreementId
------ | ---------- | ---------- | ------------- | ----------------
    1  | 1          | 2017-03-20 | 100           | 1
    2  | 1          | 2017-03-31 | 50            | null
    3  | 2          | 2017-03-21 | 100           | 1
    4  | 2          | 2017-03-23 | 125           | 2
    5  | 3          | 2017-03-15 | 90            | null
    6  | 3          | 2017-03-25 | 60            | 1
```

Sometimes they work on "PriceAgreements", and sometimes they don't.

In my Dashboard, i have a Table that groups the table TEntry by EmployeeId and Sums the TimeInMinutes. I also have a Slicer for EntryDT :

```
    EmployeeId | TimeInMinutes
-------------- | -------------
    1          | 150
    2          | 225
    3          | 150
```

I need to create 2 new columns that represent :

1. The total TimeInMinutes an Employee has worked on all PriceAgreements
   So for EmployeeId #1, the Total would be 100.
2. The total TimeInMinutes ALL Employees have worked, but only for the PriceAgreements the current Employee (current row) has worked on.

The Table would look like this (without the PriceAgreementIds in parenthesis) :

```
    EmployeeId | TimeInMinutes | TimeInMinutes on PriceAgreements | TimeInMinutes on PriceAgreements ALL other EmployeeIds
-------------- | ------------- | -------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------
    1          | 150           | 100 (PriceAgreementId=1)         | 260 (PriceAgreementId=1)
    2          | 225           | 225 (PriceAgreementId=1 and 2)   | 385 (PriceAgreementId=1 and 2)
    3          | 150           | 150 (PriceAgreementId=1)         | 260 (PriceAgreementId=1)
```

Column "TimeInMinutes on PriceAgreements" is quite easy, but the other one, i cannot find a solution...

I have this DAX expression I started, but it is not complete:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(TEntry[TimeInMinutes]), NOT ISBLANK(TEntry[PriceAgreementId]), ALL(TEmployee))
```

TEmployee is a Dimension linked to the main TEntry Table.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm throwing this on as an answer because (a) it might get you (or someone else) going in the right direction and (b) *if* it's guaranteed that an Employee would only ever have time entries corresponding to 2 price agreements, this would work - which is unlikely the case for you, but might be the case for others trying to accomplish a similar thing.

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
SUM ( TEntry[TimeInMinutes] ),
  FILTER (
    ALL ( TEntry ),
    (
        TEntry[PriceAgreementID] = MIN ( TEntry[PriceAgreementID] )
            || TEntry[PriceAgreementID] = MAX ( TEntry[PriceAgreementID] )
    )
        && TEntry[PriceAgreementID] <> BLANK ()
  )
)
```

This measure is saying: SUM the TimeInMinutes for all records in the TEntry table where the PriceAgreementID matches either the minimum OR maximum PriceAgreementID (in the context of the current row) AND the PriceAgreementID isn't blank.

The fatal flaw in this answer is in the MIN and MAX. For Employee ID 2, who has 2 PriceAgreementIDs (1 & 2) - the MIN will calculate the minutes for PriceAgreementID 1 and the MAX will calculate the minutes for PriceAgreementID 2. However, to expand to a case where there might be more than 2 PriceAgreements...I don't know how to do that.

It does work on the sample data in your question, though (since there is a max of 2 price agreements per employee):

[image: Result using a measure on the sample data above - which an employee is limited to 2 price agreements]

Typically when I'm faced with a problem like this that isn't easy to solve, I think about my data model and make sure that it conforms to a star schema as closely as possible.

In your case, an employee can have multiple price agreements, and a price agreement can be associated with many employees. That, to me, suggests a many-to-many relationship. I'd strongly recommend reading more about many-to-many relationships and whether restructuring the underlying tables (e.g. to include a bridge table) would help get you closer to the answer you need.

A good starting point might be: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many-to-many-relationships-in-power-bi-and-excel-2016/

Comment: As you said, this does not apply to my situation.
I am new to PowerBI, so i still learned form your answer and the link you shared. So thank you for that.
As for my problem, i ended up calculating the "Measure" column directly in SQL in a view representing de table TEmployee.It was much easier that way.
Thank you!